# Rails 4 - Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties"

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having some incompatibility issues with `rails` and `coffee-rails`:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      railties (= 4.0.0) x86-mingw32

    coffee-rails (= 4.0.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      railties (4.0.1)
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0' 
# Version required for this application

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'        # Rails framework
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0' # Used for advanced CSS: open-source Sass add on from Twitter 
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'  # Used for password encryption
gem 'pg', '0.15.1'      # Used for connection to Postgres
gem 'jquery-ui-rails' # Used to create user interfaces
gem 'crypt'                                       # Used for message encryption
gem 'http_parser.rb', '0.6.0.beta.2'                    # EM-Websocket dependancy
gem 'eventmachine'                    # EM-Websocket dependancy

group :assets do
  gem 'haml_coffee_assets' # Used for Coffescript template generation
  gem 'execjs' # Javascript helper
end

group :development, :test do    # Groups define the environment in which the Gem will be needed
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'   # Used for testing/TDD
  gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'    # Used for automated RSpec testing
end

group :test do                      # Used within the test environment
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.0.0'         # Used with RSpec to create automated tests
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'               # Adds more natural syntax to RSpec test scripts, and allows webpage tests
  gem 'libnotify', '0.8.0'              # Automatic notifications of Guard RSpec test results
  gem 'spork-rails'       # Used to speed up testing
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'                # Required for Guard/Spork compatibility: autostarts a Spork server with Guard
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'               # Controls external programs
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'         # Used mainly for testing Model management
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'   # Advanced CSS styling
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'     # minifies Javascript code
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0' # Allows CoffeeScript to adapt to the Assets pipeline
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.5.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1' # Advanced Javascript functions: added ease of use
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'   # Makes following links faster: uses Assets pipeline
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'     # Creates JSON structures

group :doc do           # required gem
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do        # used only within deployment
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

And `gem list railties` shows:

```
PS C:\Users\HP\Ubuntu One\A2 Computing Project\Software Development\Client> gem list railties

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

railties (4.0.1, 4.0.0)
```

The answer to a previous question I found said that running `gem install railties` fixed it, but it didnt for me. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

try running bundle update if you had a older version of railtie before.

Comment: This seems to be a WINDOWS issue.  Bundler seems to be complaining that a Windows version of railties is not installed, but it is not installing it.  In my case, the versions of railties mentioned are in fact THERE in the gems folder, so it must be that they are not the WINDOWS versions. The error message, in other words, does not adequately explain what the problem really is.

Comment: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 3.2.2, which depends on
      railties (~> 3.2.0) x86-mingw32

    rails (= 4.2.5.1) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 4.2.5.1, which depends on
      railties (= 4.2.5.1) x86-mingw32